# Connect directly to resources in an Azure virtual network via another Azure virtual network

Tags: azure, networking, routes, vpn

I'm testing using two Azure vnets in separate regions connected by a VNET to VNET connection and a point to site VPN into one of them.  Kind of like this:

```
-------------------   VPN    ---------        ---------
| Client Computer | -------> | VNET1 | -----> | VNET2 |
-------------------          ---------        ---------
                             10.1.0.0/24      10.0.0.0/24
```

Is it possible to directly access a computer/resource in VNET2 from the Client Computer, effectively routing via VNET1?

I found this article http://hindenes.com/trondsworking/2016/08/07/azure-vnet-peering that shows it can be done using the relatively new peering functionality but this doesn't work cross-region unfortunately.

I'd be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I finally got it working.  I was previously using a VNET to VNET connection between VNET1 and VNET2 but I ended up swapping it out for a Site to Site connection.  This type of connection uses Azure's 'Local Network Connection' resources which appear define the routes based on the addresses you specify when setting them up.

Adding a Route Table to the subnet, even if you don't add any routes, is really useful here since it allows you to use the 'Effective routes' function under 'Support + Troubleshooting' to view the route tables for your network.

Anyway, I followed the advice in this blog post https://www.altitude365.com/2016/04/26/azure-p2s-vpn-how-to-route-between-vnets which was pretty much the setup I was trying to achieve.  The key appears to be the adding of the P2S VPN range to VNET2 and, obviously, altering the routes on your client.  I also found this article that explains how to re-package the VPN client for distribution https://msfreaks.wordpress.com/2015/12/11/building-an-azure-lab-customizing-the-p2s-point-to-site-vpn-client.

I'd still be interested to see if this can work using a VNET to VNET connection but I've so far been unsuccessful.

@MichaelB thanks for your help.  Your answer regarding the routing pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

```
-------------------   VPN    ---------        ---------
| Client Computer | -------> | VNET1 | -----> | VNET2 |
-------------------          ---------        ---------
192.168.0.0/16               10.1.0.0/24      10.0.0.0/24
```

You would need to have a route table on Vnet1 that has 10.0.0.0/24 and 192.168.0.0/16 that both point to the virtual network gateway.

From there the virtual network gateway will decide where to route traffic.

More generically, you create a route table on a subnet to determine where traffic that originates in that subnet should be directed.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply Michael. Connecting VNET1 to VNET2 isn't the issue. The thing I'm struggling with is accessing resources running in VNET2 from the client computer that's VPN'd to VNET1. Apologies if this wasn't clear.

Comment: @SamA  Apologies I missed that from the question - I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks again @MichaelB.  Unfortunately, I don't seem t be able to get it working still.  I have added a Route Table to a VNET1 subnet with both ranges pointing to the virtual network gateway.  I also had to add a route on the client to route traffic to 10.0.0.0/24 to through the PPP adapter but I still get no reply from pings to devices on VNET2.  I'm clearly missing something! hehe